# override: M686 changes choice state CONFIG_REGULATOR_TPS6524X=m

Tags: 20.04

I downloaded kernel source from Launchpad. checkot to Ubuntu-5.4.0-81 kernel source. When I tried to build the kernel I got the above error. When I downloaded from launchpad, from 80 onwards I am facing kernel build issues without making any changes.

```
check-config: FAIL (- != m): CONFIG_SENSORS_AHC1EC0_HWMON policy<{'amd64': 'm'}>   
check-config: FAIL (- != m): CONFIG_MFD_AHC1EC0 policy<{'amd64': 'm'}>   
check-config: FAIL (- != m): CONFIG_AHC1EC0_WDT policy<{'amd64': 'm'}>   
check-config: 10454/10457 checks passed -- exit 1 make: *** [debian/rules.d/4-checks.mk:25:   
 config-prepare-check-generic] Error 1
```

Comment: check-config: FAIL (- != m): CONFIG_SENSORS_AHC1EC0_HWMON policy<{'amd64': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != m): CONFIG_MFD_AHC1EC0 policy<{'amd64': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != m): CONFIG_AHC1EC0_WDT policy<{'amd64': 'm'}>
check-config: 10454/10457 checks passed -- exit 1
make: *** [debian/rules.d/4-checks.mk:25: config-prepare-check-generic] Error 1

Comment: How exactly did you proceed? Did you follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel or some other instructions? Which ones? What was the exact last command before the error message in the title appeared? When did the other messages quoted in your question appear? Where there other messages before that?

Comment: Hello tilman, I did follow just followed the same steps from wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel .. no changes of my code.. just downloaded the code and followed the steps to build kernel before my changes. that itself is failing with the error. thats why i am asking in the forum. no code changes from me. My changes i kept is separate. the same process process worked for 5.4.0-72. 80 and above nothing working for me.any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when building with this type of command line:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-arch
```

I ran:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules clean
```

to clean kernel build files, and then:

```
$ LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-arch
```

(added LANG=C variable before fakeroot command line).

and it worked.
On my side, I was building ubuntu kernel 5.4.0 for ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, exact kernel version was 5.4.189, on a x86_64 virtualbox VM.